# Zendesk Guide Search On Enter Key Disable Function

Tags: zendesk

I have been trying to disable the search on enter key press function within Zendesk Guide but nothing seems to take effect in my theme scripts, any suggestions?

```
1.
 
  // Submit search on input enter
  $quickSearch.on('keypress', (e) => {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      search();
    }
  });
});
 
 
2.
 
const searchBox = document.querySelector("query"); searchBox.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => { if (event.keyCode === 13) {   event.preventDefault(); }});*/
 
 
3.
 
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your event listener is called before any other event listener. Try to use a global event listener and set the [useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#syntax) parameter of `addEventListener()` to `true`, then call the `stopImmediatePropagation()` method.

Something like this should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
    if (e.which == 13 && e.target.id == "query") {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopImmediatePropagation()
      //do something
    }
  }, true)
})
```